# Have a script with perl shebang, need to switch to bash in the middle

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, perl

I have a script with two blocks: 
The first block is written in perl, 
the second block is written in bash

How do I switch shells (perl --> bash) in the middle of the script?  Script attached below:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#
my @dirs = glob("*.frames");
foreach $dir (@dirs) {
   print "working on $dir\n";
   chdir $dir;
   my @digitfiles = glob ("RawImage_?.tif"); #need to make all files have 2-digit numbering for sort order to be correct
   foreach $file (@digitfiles) {
      my $newfile = $file;
      $newfile =~ s/RawImage_/RawImage_0/;
      rename $file,$newfile;
   }
   my $stackname = "../" . $dir . ".mrc";
   `tif2mrc -s *.tif $stackname`; #IMOD program to stack: -s option means treat input as signed INT
   chdir "../"; #go back up
}

#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in *.mrc; do mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}".mrc ; done
```

Comment: I'd guess you want `"${f%.*}"` instead of using `%%`

Comment: @glennjackman Possibly not. If `f` is `a.frames.mrc`, they may want to generate `a.mrc`. With a single `%`, they would just remove the `mrc` suffix and add it again.

Answer (score 27):

Just rewrite the loop in Perl:

```
for my $file (glob '*.mrc') {
    ( my $newname = $file ) =~ s/\..*/.mrc/;
    rename $file, $newname or warn "$file: $!";
}
```

Comment: Note that `mv` does (can do) more than just  `renaming`. Though in this case, using `perl`'s `rename` is probably closer to what the OP wants, as it doesn't have the issued that `mv foo.bar.mrc foo.mrc` would have if `foo.mrc` existed and was a directory.

Answer (score 19):

Ignoring the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and to answer the question in the subject, you could do:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
":" || q@<<"=END_OF_PERL"@;

# perl code here

exec "bash", "--", $0, @ARGV;
=END_OF_PERL@

# bash code here
```

`bash` will ignore the part up to the `=END_OF_PERL@` line because it's:

```
: || something <<"=END_OF_PERL@"
...
=END_OF_PERL@
```

while the first line, in perl is just two strings (`":"` and [`q@quoted-string@`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)) ORed together, so a no-op.

`=END_OF_PERL@` in `perl` is the start of a [`pod` (documentation)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) section so ignored by `perl`.

Note that if you want to pass variables from `perl` to `bash`, you have to export them to the environment (though you could also use arguments; here we're forwarding the list of arguments the `perl` script received to the `bash` script):

```
$ENV{ENV_VAR} = $perl_var;
```

The code assumes the `perl` part doesn't change the current working directory, as otherwise if `$0` was a relative path, it would become invalid when passed to `bash`. To work around that, you can take an absolute path of the script at the start with:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
":" || q@<<"=END_OF_PERL"@;
use Cwd "fast_abs_path";
my $script_path = fast_abs_path $0;

# perl code here

exec "bash", "--", $script_path, @ARGV;
=END_OF_PERL@

# bash code here
```

That's one example of a polyglot script, a script that is valid code in more than one language. If you enjoy those tricks, you can have a look at [that more extreme one](/a/71137) here or that [codegolf Q&A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102370).

`perldoc perlrun` shows another example of a `sh`+`perl` polyglot, but this time with `sh` being called first (for systems that don't support she-bangs).

Comment: That kind of tricks are nice when they work, but when they break, you loose all your sanity and all your hair.

Answer (score 7):

You can't *switch* interpreters, but you can spawn a new shell process, then return to perl:

```
my $sh_code = <<'END_SH'
for f in *.mrc; do mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}".mrc ; done
END_SH

system 'bash', '-c', $sh_code
```

Or you can replace the current perl process with a shell

```
exec 'bash', '-c', $sh_code
```

But as @choroba answers, perl is a general purpose language and can handle just about any task.

Answer (score 2):

You could do everything in Perl, or everything in a shell script. Mixing languages is usually a bit messy though.

The shell script version may look *something like* this (with `bash`, for example):

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=( *.frames )

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    printf 'Working on "%s"\n' "$dir"

    cd "$dir"

    digitfiles=( RawImage_?.tif )

    for file in "${digitfiles[@]}"; do
        newfile="RawImage_0${file#RawImage_}"
        mv "$file" "$newfile"
    done

    stackname="../$dir.mrc"
    tif2mrc -s *.tif "$stackname"

    cd ..
done

for f in *.mrc; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}".mrc
done
```

Or, slightly more idiomatic (now with plain `sh`, but using a `find` that understands `-execdir`):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Renaming TIFF files'

find *.frames -type f -name 'RawImage_?.tif' \
    -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "RawImage_0${1#RawImage_}"' sh {} ';'

for d in *.frames; do
    printf 'Processing "%s"...\n' "$d"
    tif2mrc -s "$d"/*.tif "${d%%.*}.mrc"
done
```

(both examples are tested only with regards to filename generation)

Change `sh -c` to `sh -cx` to get a bit of output for each renamed file, or add `-print` before `-execdir`.

With `-execdir`, the given shell command will be executed with the directory of the found file as its working directory. `{}` (and `$1` within the subshell) will be the basename of the found file.

If `tif2mrc` *needs* to be run inside the directory of the TIFF files, then change the loop to

```
for d in *.frames; do
    printf 'Processing "%s"...\n' "$d"
    (cd "$d" && tif2mrc -s *.tif "../${d%%.*}.mrc" )
done
```

---

Note that in Perl, using backticks to execute a shell command will return the output of that command. You may instead use

```
system("tif2mrc -s *.tif $stackname");
```

if you're not interested in the output of `tif2mrc`.

Also, it's confusing to read a script or program that changes directories back and forth.  It can additionally lead to unwanted things if a directory does not exist (the `chdir("..");` would then take you up one directory level too high).

To properly do this, either execute the command with a displaced working directory, as in my last shell example, or properly check the return code of the initial `chdir()` in Perl (this would potentially still lead to code that may be hard to read and follow).

Comment: `system("tif2mrc -s *.tif $stackname");` invokes a shell (because of the `*`), so the content of the `$stackname` perl variable is interpreted as shell code, making it a sort of command injection vulnerability (even without the `*`, it would be a command injection vulnerability). The `system('tif2mrc', '-s', '*.tif', $stackname)` version doesn't have the vulnerability, but the `*.tif` wouldn't be expanded. You'd need to use `perl`'s `glob()`.