# Set default interpreter in fish shell

Tags: fish, shebang

I've installed [`mill`](http://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/) on arch linux with fish as my default shell.  Since the file `/usr/bin/mill` doesn't start with a shebang, fish won't execute the file.  Instead it responds with

```
$ mill
Failed to execute process '/usr/bin/mill'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file '/usr/bin/mill' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

I can execute mill with `bash -c 'mill'` but I don't want to be doing that all the time.  Nor do I want to add that as an alias just for mill.  Is it possible to configure fish to always use sh or bash when there isn't a shebang in the script instead of failing?  Or maybe there is an operating system level problem?

*edit:*
Mill is just an example.  I've encountered this feature of fish numerous times with different scripts that I shouldn't be editing.  That's why I'm looking for a way to forever avoid the feature not a one off fix for just mill.

Comment: It seems to me that the author of the mill software should add an appropriate sh-bang line to it. Initial appearances are that it tries to be a [polyglot script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392903/117549), and clearly doesn't support fish.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/491419/117549

Comment: Why don't you want to add an alias? That's exactly what they're for.

Comment: @glennjackman I've encountered this feature of fish multiple times with files I shouldn't be editing.  I don't want to add an alias for every one.  I want a permament solution.

Comment: It's not onerous: `alias mill 'bash /usr/bin/mill'; funcsave mill` is all it takes.

Comment: You're missing the point of the question entirely.  I've run into this problem before and I don't want to again.  I'm geniunely curious if it's possible to configure fish to behave like bash or sh would and just execute the file without a shebang.  `mill` is just an example problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.

You can check its [source code](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/ca5427865d0ad7be5564d41a16173d177a51bb02/src/exec.cpp#L133):

```
        execve(actual_cmd, argv, envv);
        err = errno;

        // Something went wrong with execve, check for a ":", and run /bin/sh if encountered. This is a
        // weird predecessor to the shebang that is still sometimes used since it is supported on
        // Windows. OK to not use CLO_EXEC here because this is called after fork and the file is
        // immediately closed.
```

Notice how its using `execve` (not `execvp` or `execlp`, which have a fall-back to `/bin/sh path` in case of `ENOEXEC`) and it will only run the script with `/bin/sh` if it starts with `:` (itself quite a dubious feature; especially since `fish` will also use it in the case of errors other than `ENOEXEC`).

But if you can edit the script to add a `:` at the beginning, you can just as well edit it to add a proper she-bang.